# Error using a button in view to trigger action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
Rails 5.2
```

In my routes.rb, I have the following:

```
put 'lights/reset_node', to: 'lights#reset_node'
```

When I run rake routes, I get:

```
lights_reset_node PUT    /lights/reset_node(.:format)  lights#reset_node
```

In lights_controller.rb, I have:

def reset_node
    #TODO write method
  end

In my view, I have the following:

```
= link_to lights_reset_node_path(:node => @node), :method => :put do
  button.btn.btn-secondary type="button"
    = t('device.show.reset_node_button')
```

However, when I click on the button, I get the following:

```
Unknown action
The action 'update' could not be found for LightsController
```

Comment: Can you share your `routes.rb` file?  Are you sure there isn't a route higher up than this getting triggered with the same url?  I am thinking of something like `resources :lights`

Comment: routes.rb is very complicated, I missed the automatically added resources: lights. I removed it and it's now working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue, just to explain more in-depth, was that routes inside routes.rb are read in order.  So when a route with the same URL is hit first it goes with that route and never goes further down the file.  So make sure your routes in the file are in the correct order.

In your case, this was placed higher in the routes.rb file, and so that is why it was looking at the wrong route.

```
resources :lights
```

As you stated, once you moved that down below your other route `put 'lights/reset_node', to: 'lights#reset_node'` it worked because now this was higher up in the order.

Comment: This worked. When the scaffold is automatically generated, Rails adds a reources statement to the beginning of the file

Comment: Yep, I think a lot of people have been caught by this before, I certainly have